# php Converting an object implementing ArrayAccess in array

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion, arrayaccess

When you implement the _toString method on a class, you are able to convert the object in string

```
$string =(string) $object
```

Is there an equivalent for converting in array

```
$array=(array) $object
```

From what I have tested, with this code, the attributes of the objet are transformed in index of the array, even if this object implement ArrayAccess.

I expected that casting an object with array access, I would obtain an array thith the same values I could access with the object

```
public class MyObject implements ArrayAccess{
     private $values;
     public function __construct(array $values){
        $this->values=$values;
     }
     public function offsetSet($name,$value){
        $this->values[$name]=$value;
     }
     //etc...
}

$myObject=new MyObject(array('foo'=>'bar');

$asArray=(array)$myObject;

print_r($asArray);
// expect array('foo'=>'bar')
// but get array('MyObjectvalues'=>array('foo'=>'bar'));
```

I also Notice that the native ArrayObject class has a the behavior I expected

Comment: Either derive from ArrayObject and reuse getArrayCopy; or reimplement it by just returning the $values prop. Casting won't work, as there's no `__toArray` handling.

Comment: `public function MyObject implements ArrayAccess{` <-- this is not valid PHP syntax. You want `class MyObject implements ArrayAccess { ...`.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no [magic function](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to cast object as array.

`ArrayObject` is implemented with C and has weird specific behaviors.

Implement custom method `asArray` and use it.

Comment: A vague response, offering no resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's **impossible** to write a general function:

```php
/*
 * @return array ArrayAccess object converted into an array
 */
function (ArrayAccess $arrayAccessObject): array { /* ... */ }
```

Why? Because `ArrayAccess` interface just gives a way to use `$aa[/*argument*/]` syntax, but does not give a way to iterate over all possible arguments.

We used to think that `array` has a finite number of keys. However `ArrayAccess` let us create objects having an infinite set of keys (note, the same concerns `Traversable`: i.e. prime numbers are "traversable").

For example, one can write a class, implementing `ArrayAccess`, that acts like a HTTP client with a cache (I'm not saying that it's a good idea; it's just an example). Then `offsetExists($url)` tells if a URL gives 200 or not, `offsetGet($url)` returns a content of a URL, `offsetUnset($url)` clears cached content, `offsetSet` throws a `LogicException`, 'cause setting a value makes no sense in this context.

```
// ...
if (empty($client['https://example.com/file.csv'])) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Cannot download the file');
}
$content = $client['https://example.com/file.csv'];
// ...
```

Or maybe one wants to read/write/unset (delete) files with `ArrayAccess`.

Or maybe something like (set of even numbers is infinite):

```php
$even = new EvenNumberChecker(); // EvenNumberChecker implements ArrayAccess
$even[2]; // true
$even[3]; // false
$even[5.6]; // throws UnexpectedValueException
isset($even[7.8]); // false
$even[0] = $value; // throws LogicException
```

`ArrayAccess` objects from academic examples above cannot be converted into finite arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode` and `json_encode` to get the most generic function for it:

```
public static function toArray(ArrayAccess $array): array
{
    return json_decode(
        json_encode($array),
        true
    );
}
```